# Light bulb broke in oven, wire still attached

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, oven

I have a gas oven. The electrical light bulb burned out, and when I went to unscrew to replace it, it broke off. The metal ring is still in the socket, the wire is attached, and the glass bulb is detached, but unbroken. How on earth am I gonna get this thing out?

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You can use needle nose pliers to grip the metal of the broken off light bulb. Grip the edge and unscrew it. Turn off the power to the stove at the breaker before you do this or unplug it if the plug is accessible. You **MUST** make sure that the light socket is unpowered while you stick pliers into a broken off light bulb.

Comment: They say you can also do by pressing in  a potato or a carrot and gently unscrew it, but I am an electrician and have always used a needlenose. Just a suggestion or poor attempt at humor. PS regardless always turn power off moisture is also a conductor so stay safe.

Comment: The carrot and potato idea suggests that a medium sized two-tined fork could be gently forced into the interior of the base of the broken bulb and twisted.

Comment: OK, I will do this and turn the power off first. Another question, maybe silly, but I am a new homeowner, so here goes: It's a brand new gas stove, if I unplug the electricity to it, will the "fire" go out and will I have to relight it somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Almost certainly it has a spark igniter and not a pilot light so, unplugging should not  cause a special problem. However, since it is new, do you have the owner's manual? It would tell you what the startup procedure is.

Comment: I do have the owners manual--didn't even think to check there lol. I'll do that. I'm a little nervous around gas and fire, so I am hoping it will stay lit somehow.

Comment: If you are worried about leaking gas with the power off, also close the shut-off valve for the oven (not the one for the whole house).